# Let $\lbrace R_i \rbrace _{i=1}^{n}$ be a set of rings. Show that $e=(e_1,...,e_n)$ is the identity of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assuming $\lbrace R_i \rbrace _{i=1}^{n}$ be a set of rings, show that $$e=(e_1,...,e_n)$$ is the identity of $$R=R_1 \times R_2 \times ... \times R_n$$ if and only if $e_i$ is the identity of $R_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. I come across this statement when $R$ is the internal direct product of $R_i$ but here, we don have this assumption. How do we tackle this problem?

Comment: Apparently your rings are assumed to come with an identity element (not everybody agrees on this definition). But then giving the identity is part of the _definition_ of a direct product of rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backwards: If $e=(e_1,...,e_n)$ is the identity of $R \implies \forall x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in R,  $ we have $ex=x$ which, since we're dealing with a Cartesian Product, means that $ \forall i$ we have $x_ie_i=x_i \implies e_i $ is  the identity in $R_i$.

Forwards: If $e_i$ is the identity for $R_i \implies \forall x_i\in R_i$ we have $ e_ix_i=x_i \implies$ for arbitrary $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in R$ we have $(x_1,...,x_n)(e_1,...,e_n)=(x_1e_1,...,x_ne_n)=(x_1,...,x_n)$ by definition of Cartesian Product and the fact that $e_i$ is the identity of $R_i$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Suppose $e=(e_1,\cdots ,e_n)$ is the identity of $R$. Take now an arbitrary element $x\in R_i$ (so fix some $i$ as well). Consider the element $y=(0,0,\cdots , e_i,0,0,\cdots)\in R$ with $e_i$ at position $i$. Now, spell out what the identity property of $e$ means for $y$? Conclude from that that $e_i$ is the identity element in $R_i$.

Try doing the other direction now (should be easier).

Comment: for the forward direction , since $ye=(0,...,e_i e_i,...,0)=(0,...,e_i e_i,...,0)$, we have $e_i e_i=e_i \implies e_i=1$, is this correct?

Comment: For the element $y$, how do we know for sure $y$ exists?